# Pra que serve um arquivo de extensão TT?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, template

Bem, eu estava pesquisando aí pela internet uma maneira de criar uma *string* como *template*, baseando num arquivo de *template*. Deparei-me com uma resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33112328/3096922) que fala sobre arquivos `.tt`, para usar um *template* em "tempo de execução".

Eu gostaria de saber mais sobre esse arquivos:

- Pra que serve esse extensão `.tt` e como utilizá-lo?
- O que preciso fazer para usá-lo no Visual Studio, por exemplo?
- É seguro utilizá-lo para quais fins? Por exemplo, pretendo usar para montar corpo de e-mails (uso Webforms :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É um arquivo de *template* utilizado pelo Visual Studio ([T4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit)). Ele é usado para criar *snippets* de código e outras formas que dão uma base do que pretende fazer.

Era usado um pouco mais para geração de código, mas o Roslyn ([.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101)) diminuiu a sua necessidade. Ainda que ele pode ser usado como base para o Roslyn gerar algum código. Quase tudo onde ele era necessário tem ferramenta melhor hoje em dia.

Ele não foi exatamente criado para *templates* de dados, e sim de códigos. Mas nada impede de usá-lo para seus e-mails, só não sei se tem muita infra pronta para isto, você terá que interpretá-lo. nem tem documentação recente de [`TextTransformation`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.texttransformation?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=visualstudiosdk-2019) . Mais [documentação do Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh191512(v%3Dvs.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Tem [algo um pouco mais novo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Eu usaria o [Razor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111209/101) com *template* para e-mails. Na maior parte dos casos nem isso precisaria, uma simples interpolação pode ser suficiente.

Nem tem mais ferramenta no Visual Studio.

Segurança depende de como você usa. Ingenuamente pode ser inseguro.